# Why does simple imageview app force closes after device is turned on from sleep

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, gallery

I have developed simple imageview app that is suppose to play background music along with imaple sliding from lef to right.. But my problem is that whenever my app is running on the device and device goes to sleep..After turning on it display force close dialogue box, and app just force closes..What could be wrong?.. Please provide solution for this issue..Following are my codes and logcat errors

Logcat errors

```
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.manishkpr.viewpagerimagegallery/com.manishkpr.viewpagerimagegallery.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.seekTo(Native Method)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at com.manishkpr.viewpagerimagegallery.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:86)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
08-30 02:14:31.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     ... 10 more
```

Mainactivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer oursong;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ImageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
         oursong.seekTo(0);
         oursong.start();

         viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
         adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
         viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


         viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(MyViewPagerListener);
    }

    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate menu resource file.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

            // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

            // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
            mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
            // Return true to display menu
            return true;
    }

    // Call to update the share intent
    private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
            if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
                    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

           if(oursong != null){
               oursong.release();
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
          super.onResume();

         /*
          * This is the important part, basically since your releasing the song
          * in onPause() you are getting rid of its reference, in this case check
          * if your song is null then if it is re-create it, else you can reuse the
          * the original, but i suspect that calling release() in onPause() allows the
          * song to get cleaned up by Java's Garbage Collector.
          */
         if(oursong == null){
            oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
            oursong.seekTo(0); // You will probably want to save an int to restore here
            oursong.start();
         }else{
            oursong.seekTo(0);
            oursong.start();
         }

    }

   /*
    * May want to add two methods here: onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outstate) &
    * onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) to maintain playback position
    * in onResume instead of just restarting the song.
    */

   private final OnPageChangeListener MyViewPagerListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
              if (pos == adapter.getCount() - 1){
                 // adding null checks for safety
                 if(oursong != null){
                    oursong.pause();
                 }

               } else if (!oursong.isPlaying()){ 

                // adding null check for safety
                if(oursong != null){
                    oursong.start();
                }
              }         
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

 }
```

imageadapter.java

```
 import java.io.IOException;

    import android.app.WallpaperManager;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        Context context;
        private final int[] GalImages = new int[] {
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.two,
            R.drawable.three
        };    
        ImageAdapter(Context context){
            this.context=context;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
          return GalImages.length;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
          return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
          ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
          int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_small);
          imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
          imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
          imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);  
          imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View view) {

                        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager  = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
                        try {
                                myWallpaperManager.setResource(GalImages[position]);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                        }      
               }
               });
          ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
          return imageView;
        }
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
          ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Try removing `seekTo`  from `onResume()` in `if` condition

Comment: @Aniruddha..It didn't solve my problem...Just to be clear you wanted me to remove seekTo in if condition and not the else condition right ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see that [`seekTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(int)) will throw the `IllegalStateException` if `MediaPlayer` is not initialized. In `onPause` you `release` the object, and in `onResume` you use it again without initialization. BTW, you should always set `oursong` to NULL after being released.

try the following:

```
private int pos = 0;
@Override
protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

       if(oursong != null){
           pos = oursong.getCurrentPosition();
           oursong.release();
           oursong = null;
        }
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
      super.onResume();

     /*
      * This is the important part, basically since your releasing the song
      * in onPause() you are getting rid of its reference, in this case check
      * if your song is null then if it is re-create it, else you can reuse the
      * the original, but i suspect that calling release() in onPause() allows the
      * song to get cleaned up by Java's Garbage Collector.
      */
     oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
     oursong.seekTo(pos); // You will probably want to save an int to restore here
     oursong.start();
}
```

Comment: @suitianshi...could you please provide the code ? It would be helpful for me to understand..as I am currently new to android ..and thanks for reply..

Comment: @user123456, see my update answer please. As you see, you should release the MediaPlayer in `onPause` and create it in `onResume`

Comment: @suitianshi...your suggested code did work..However, I would like to resume the music from where it was left..Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: @user123456, you can `getCurrentPosition` in `onPause` before release it and pass the value to `seekTo` in `onResume`. This should work.

Comment: ..thanks so much ..this problem was bothering me since this morning...sorry for being greedy ....but If possible ..can you please provide the solution for this question too....thanks again....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515083/starting-and-stopping-background-music-smoothly-in-android-imageview?rq=1